# Linear Algebra: Kernel to formula for Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Show work to find a formula for a *nontrivial* (EDIT) linear transformation $T : {\Bbb R}^3 \to {\Bbb R}$ whose kernel contains the three
points $(x_1, y_1, z_1) = (−6, 1, 2), (x_2, y_2, z_2) = (−13, −2, 1)$ and $(x_3, y_3, z_3) = (7, 3, 1)$.

I know that because it is being mapped to lower dimensional space that it is going to the $0$ vector. Also, that because it contains the origin that means we can think about the three vectors in the kernel as being parallel to the position vectors of the same value. However, I don't how to use this information to work backwards from the kernel to find the formula.

Comment: **Hint:** $(−6, 1, 2) -(7, 3, 1) = (−13, −2, 1)$.

Comment: We could always take the trivial linear transformation, the way it is phrased.

Comment: There is no reason to close this question, in my opinion. Even if it is not very exciting, the question is clear and the OP explained his attempt to solve it.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I disagree about the clarity of the question.  As pointed out by Chris Custer, the trivial map gets the job done.  It is hard to believe that this is the intention, thus one suspects that part of the question is missing.  Until this issue is rectified, the question ought to be closed.

Comment: @xander-henderson Another solution is to edit the question, as I just did.

Answer (score 1):

They are linearly dependent, since the determinant of the matrix whose rows are the vectors is zero.  So, take any two, since they are pairwise independent.

Then, say, extend $\{(-6,1,2),(7,3,1)\}$ to a basis for $\Bbb R^3$.  You could use $e_1=(1,0,0)$.  Then define $T$ by $T(-6,1,2)=T(7,3,1)=0$, and $T(e_1)=1$.

This is one $T$ with the right kernel.  There certainly are others.

Comment: My professor said that there is a way to do this with cross products (my first thought was something similar to this) do you know how you would do it with cross products?

Comment: Take the cross product of two of the vectors to get a third that is linearly independent of the first two.  Define $T$ to be zero on the first two, and anything nonzero on the cross product.